# How to integrate google app engine endpoints module with firebase ?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase

How to connect google app engine endpoints module to firebase?

I read this https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio but it uses " `For App Engine Java Servlet Module`".

Do we need application server for google app engine java endpoints module as we need application server for GCM?

Comment: You should try to make your title into a focussed question.

Comment: Sir i edited my title. I want to use google app engine API as a server and firebase as a database store. I am not sure whether can we connect app engine end point module to firebase.

Comment: Do you want firebase database for realtime database access?, because rest of the facilities that firebase database provides is already available with App Engine datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints, GCM, and Firebase - these are all independent things.

When you say app server, I guess you are talking about a GAE app, so you should note that Firebase does not work well with GAE (you have to leave an extra thread listening which is not how GAE works).

If you are new to these things I suggest you start with one at a time.  You can create an app that uses Firebase without any of the others.  (But be careful - Firebase is a proprietary service that is quite expensive.)

Or, forget about Firebase and write an app that talks to GAE using either endpoints, or just a plain servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Cloud Endpoints with Firebase. While Datastore may be a better choice depending on your situation, I have had the need to integrate with an existing firebase. 
Below is an example of how to do this. This comes from a working example, I have altered some names.

NOTE: this example inits the firebase app every time, you'll need to do a check to see if the firebase app is already initialized or the second time the endpoint is hit you'll get an error,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


package com.example.mypackage;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class MyClass {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Echo.class.getName());
    public static void main() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/my-service-account.json");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()             
    .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("/foo");

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String post = dataSnapshot.toString();
                    LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, post);
                    System.out.println(post);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "cancel");

                    // ...
                }
            });
            ref.setValue("bar");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some error handling code here
            LOGGER.log( Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e );
        }
    }
}
```